# Unlocking the device by Ui automator 2.0

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm am creating a ui-automator test for which I have to unlock my device and perform some task. I have removed all kind of locks in my phone (only unlock key and home key will unlock my device by simple click ) but when I'm using the following command it clicks the home button but rest of the things does not work. Is there any solution to unlock device using ui-automator?

Note : They work if the device is already unlocked

```
 mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    mDevice.pressHome(); // only screen ligths are on

    UiObject CallB = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().description("Phone")); // test fails here :(
    CallB.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function:

Device resume:

```
mDevice.wakeUp();
```

Device suspend:

```
mDevice.sleep();
```